# Python. KeyError after checking that key exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `KeyError` message when I try to get a value from dictionary by key. Before get a value by key I check that key is exist. Here is my code:

```
def getTweetSentiment(tweet_text):
    print sentiment_words #{u'limited': -1, u'cut': 2, ...}
    sentiment = 0
    words = extractWordsFromTweet(tweet_text)
    for word in words:
        test = word.lower() #test is unicode
        if test in sentiment_words.keys(): #Here I check that key is in a list of keys.
            temp = sentiments_words[test]  #!And here throws the KeyError exception
            sentiment = sentiment + temp
    return sentiment
```

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: The call to `keys()` is redundant. `test in sentiment_words` does the same thing.

Comment: In Python there is a habit saying that instead of checking if something is possible, `try` to do it, and handle a exception. So, I think that more pythonic approach would be `try: sentiment+= sentiments_words[word.lower()] except KeyError: pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line shows `sentiment_words` and the other shows `sentiments_words` (note the `s` after `sentiment`

```
sentiment_words
sentiments_words
```

Note that the better solution might be this:

```
word = sentiment_words.get(test)
if word is not None:  # the `is not None` part is only required if '' could occur as a word
    sentiment += word
```

Or the simpler version for this case (as Chepner suggested):

```
sentiment += sentiment_words.get(test, 0)
```

Comment: That should really be `if word is not None`; an empty string may be a valid `word`.

Comment: You can even combine this into one statement, since adding zero is idempotent: `sentiment += sentiment_words.get(test, 0)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that's an implementation detail which depends on the case. An empty string is not a word by definition ;)

Comment: @Wolph alright then: because [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says so!